# Browser extensions to automatically alter HTTP headers?

Tags: browser-addons, http

Can I **automatically** alter/remove/add specific HTTP headers according to criteria such as URL (by regex) and maybe referrer?

EDIT: Alternatively, what local proxy would do this, preferably for free?

I'm primarily interested in Chrome, but this question relates to all browsers. If nothing is available for Chrome I might resort to whatever browser does have a solution.

I have a few sites that I always keep open. I decided to consolidate them into one page by containing each one in an iframe. At least one of the pages I use doesn't like this idea; it apparently sends `X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN` to protect me from the black hats. I appreciate the gesture, but I'd like to use the data they send me in the way that makes the most sense to me.

So I decided that the simplest way around this is to detect that my page is the referrer (I could put a dummy variable in the iframe's query string if necessary) and strip X-FRAME-OPTIONS from the response so Chrome doesn't realize the page wanted to disable cross-domain embeds.

I tried searching the Chrome Web Store and Google but couldn't find anything. Surely there's something? I know there's Live HTTP Headers in Firefox and similar in Chrome, but that requires that I edit the headers manually. This task should be automated.

Comment: Does it have to be a browser extension? Would a local proxy be acceptable? There's a lot of local proxies that allow you to modify HTTP headers and even the content.

Comment: Bob, I had never heard of such a thing. That would be perfect... I've edited the question.

Comment: [This appears to be a way to do it][1], using Apache as a proxy server.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154441/set-up-an-http-proxy-to-insert-a-header

Comment: as far as proxies go, I think [Fiddler](https://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) should work, if you're running Windows somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, there are many local proxies that can accomplish this. A common one is [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/), a caching proxy. [Polipo](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/%7Ejch/software/polipo/) is another one, and apparently lighter than Squid. There are many other options, such as those listed [here](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/%7Ejch/software/polipo/polipo.html#Caching).

---

### Squid

Their [ContentAdaptation wiki article](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ContentAdaptation) lists different methods of modifying the stream. The simplest is in the [`squid.conf`](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ConfiguringSquid#What_does_the_squid.conf_file_do.3F) configuration file, with [`request_header_replace`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/request_header_replace/) and [`reply_header_replace`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/reply_header_replace/). If you want to remove headers entirely, you can use [`request_header_access`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/request_header_access/) and [`reply_header_access`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/reply_header_access/).

In your case, you probably want `reply_header_access X-Frame-Options deny all`, which should remove the header. You could also modify it to reply with anything other than `SAMEORIGIN` or `DENY`, which will allow it as per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6767901/1030702) (but this is a special case, and apparently undocumented, so better to just remove it).

Remember, you need to run Squid with the argument/option `--enable-http-violations` to use these options.

You may also wish to [disable the caching aspect](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ConfiguringSquid#Can_I_make_Squid_proxy_only.2C_without_caching_anything.3F) of Squid.

---

### Polipo

The [`censoredHeaders`](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/%7Ejch/software/polipo/polipo.html#Censoring-headers) variable accepts a list of HTTP headers to block. You can add `From, X-Frame-Options` to this list. See [here](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/%7Ejch/software/polipo/polipo.html#Running) for instructions on configuring Polipo.

There is no clear-cut way to disable caching in Polipo - apparently it doesn't use a buffer in memory, instead always saving to disk. However, you can force it to always request a new page by setting the `maxExpiresAge`, `maxAge` and `maxNoModifiedAge` variables to 0 (maybe 1, if 0 does not work). See [here](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/%7Ejch/software/polipo/polipo.html#Caching).

Comment: Squid is also included with custom router firmware such as DD-WRT and Tomato, and [you can do fun things with it](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html).

Comment: Thanks... It looks like I have a lot of personal research & devel-, err, configuration to do.

Answer (score 3):

I know you prefer Chrome, but its architecture makes it hard for stuff like this, because they try to isolate things a lot.

A quickie Firefox plugin search found [modifyheaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/modify-headers/).

As far as proxies go, maybe [Fiddler](https://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) would work.

I haven't tested either of these personally, but both seem like they may do what you want.

Comment: I actually was using Firefox not too long ago, but I transitioned to Chrome. Now both are on my task bar. (Although I forgot to mention it in my edit, and it wasn't relevant before then, I *am* on Windows.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For Chrome, there exists: [Ignore X-Frame headers](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ignore-x-frame-headers/gleekbfjekiniecknbkamfmkohkpodhe). Working nicely for me!

I'm using https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers/ on Firefox when I need the same thing - requires some minimal configuration.

Answer (score 0):

What about **Modify headers for Chrome** https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modify-headers-for-google/innpjfdalfhpcoinfnehdnbkglpmogdi

It's good for example for adding debug headers for users of Akamai's caching platform