# Firefox: Disable x-frame-options limitations for a given origin site

Tags: firefox

The RSS reader I use has a feature to load the linked site in a frame.  And has useful related features connecting that to navigation of feeds/items.  But lots of sites now set x-frame-options which mean that they simply don't load, with no error message or any other indicator.

I trust that my RSS reader is in fact not trying to clickjack me.  I want to enable it to frame any site, regardless of the x-frame-options they set.

Is there an about:config entry or an extension that would help here?  Especially if I can specifically whitelist this domain, so that only frames *it* creates skip x-frame-options.

Comment: I'm pretty sure none of the browsers have any configuration for this.  This other question may help you out though: [Browser extensions to automatically alter HTTP headers?](http://superuser.com/q/506447/820)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by writing a quick [extension](https://github.com/arantius/nbfod) using [nsITraceableChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/NsITraceableChannel) to alter the response.  Not the request.